# Search Cloudwatch logs for AWS Xray trace ID in code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I've been experimenting with using AWS Xray as a testing tool using Typescript and the AWS Xray SDK.

We have a highly distributed system using API Gateway, Lambdas, Event Bridge, DynamoDB, etc.

We currently log data in each lambda that is currently being manually spot checked to test a system to make sure each step is progressing through the system as expected.   The hope is to use the AWS Trace ID to query logs and validate all the information is flowing through the system as expected.

When we launch our test we get back a trace ID from our initial API Gateway/Lambda call and can use it to get trace information about each step in the process.

I was expecting we'd be able to get information in cloudwatch logs given the traceID.  I thought it would be available to get the log group via Segments/Doc from calling the AWS Xray Client.  I see a lot of interesting information in the documents, but nothing about logs.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch ServiceLen is able to correlate application logs with X-Ray traces when the following 2 conditions are met.

1. The application logs group name has been embedded in X-Ray trace raw data.
2. The trace ids are injected in application logs under the same App logs group embedded in X-Ray traces.

For API Gateway, Lambdas, the application logs group name are embedded in X-Ray traces out of box, so you don't need to do anything specially.

For the trace Id injection to application logs, today it is only supported by X-Ray/OTel Java SDKs. For Javascript applications, you'll need to inject and print X-Ray trace ids `AWS-XRAY-TRACE-ID: 1-5d77f256-19f12e4eaa02e3f76c78f46a` to your application log entries yourself.

**Example Log statement with ID injection**

```
2019-09-10 18:58:30.844 [nio-5000-exec-4]  AWS-XRAY-TRACE-ID: 1-5d77f256-19f12e4eaa02e3f76c78f46a@1ce7df03252d99e1 WARN 1 - Your logging message here
```